# Java Blink JButton during 2 seconds

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, background-color, blink

I want the program to wait 2 seconds while blinking the button.
I have this code for the blinking button:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Color;

public class a
{
    static JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    static JButton button = new JButton("Hello");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        frame.add(button);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        blinking();   //this is the blinking part
        //this is where the waiting 2 seconds should be
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Popup message", "Title", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        //rest of the code of my program
    }

    private void blinking() {
        button.setOpaque(true);
        Timer blinkTimer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
            boolean on=false;
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // blink the button background on and off
                button.setBackground( on ? Color.YELLOW : null);
                on = !on;
            }
        });
        blinkTimer.start();
    }
}
```

I want the program to blink during 2 seconds and then open the `JOptionPane`. What it is doing is that it opens the `JOptionPane` without waiting 2 seconds.
I have tried using the `Thread.sleep(2000)` for the waiting but it doesn't seem to work, the button doesn't blink during those 2000 miliseconds of waiting time.
Any suggestions?

**NOTE :**
I cannot move the JOptionPane out of main().

Answer (score 3):

Use the Timer that you already have to help you identify when 2 seconds is up, and you can do this by counting inside of your Timer how many times the actionPerformed method is called. When it is called 4 times (2 seconds), stop the Timer.  It's simple:

```
Timer blinkTimer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
    private int count = 0;
    private int maxCount = 4;
    private boolean on = false;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (count >= maxCount) {
            button.setBackground(null);
            ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
        } else {
            button.setBackground( on ? Color.YELLOW : null);
            on = !on;
            count++;
        }
    }
});
blinkTimer.start();
```

---

You're also informing me that you want to somehow pause the execution of some of your program during this blink, and for that I suggest that you create a method, say `enableExecution(boolean)` that does this for you, that you call before starting the Timer and that you call again when the Timer is finished, something like:

```
Timer blinkTimer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
    private int count = 0;
    private int maxCount = 4;
    private boolean on = false;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (count >= maxCount) {
            button.setBackground(null);
            ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
            enableExecution(true);   //  ***** re-enable execution of whatever *****

        } else {
            button.setBackground( on ? Color.YELLOW : null);
            on = !on;
            count++;
        }
    }
});

enableExecution(false);   //  ***** disable execution of whatever *****
blinkTimer.start();
```

---

**Edit**
Regarding your edited code, I still fee that best solution is again to call that code that displays the dialog from within your timer. If your problem is that the class that calls the timer doesn't have the information needed to appropriately show in the dialog, then consider passing this information into that class. For example:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class BetterA extends JPanel {
   private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 500;
   private JButton button = new JButton("Hello");

   // information needed by the dialog:
   private String message;
   private String title;

   public BetterA(String message, String title) {
      add(button);
      blinking();

      // set the dialog information
      this.message = message;
      this.title = title;
   }

   private void blinking() {
      button.setOpaque(true);
      Timer blinkTimer = new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new ActionListener() {
         private int count = 0;
         private int maxTime = 2000;
         private boolean on = false;

         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (count * TIMER_DELAY >= maxTime) {
               button.setBackground(null);
               ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
               Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(BetterA.this);
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(win, message, title,
                     JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            } else {
               button.setBackground(on ? Color.YELLOW : null);
               on = !on;
               count++;
            }
         }
      });
      blinkTimer.start();
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      String myMessage = "Popup message";
      String myTitle = "Some Title";

      BetterA mainPanel = new BetterA(myMessage, myTitle);

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("BetterA");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

---

**Edit 2**

Another option is to use Swing's innate PropertyChangeListener support. For example:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class BetterA2 extends JPanel {
   private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 500;
   private static final int MAX_TIME = 2000;
   private static final String READY = "ready";
   private JButton button = new JButton("Hello");

   public BetterA2() {
      add(button);
      blinking();
   }

   private void blinking() {
      button.setOpaque(true);
      Timer blinkTimer = new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new ActionListener() {
         private int count = 0;
         private boolean on = false;

         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (count * TIMER_DELAY >= MAX_TIME) {
               button.setBackground(null);
               ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();

               // !!!
               firePropertyChange(READY, READY, null);
            } else {
               button.setBackground(on ? Color.YELLOW : null);
               on = !on;
               count++;
            }
         }
      });
      blinkTimer.start();
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      final BetterA2 mainPanel = new BetterA2();
      mainPanel.addPropertyChangeListener(BetterA2.READY,
            new PropertyChangeListener() {

               @Override
               public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(mainPanel, "Popup message",
                        "Title", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
               }
            });

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("BetterA");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: thank you, it does stop. But what I want is for the program to do nothing during those 2 seconds (just blink) and then continue with it's execution

Comment: @dan_san_1: Your statement above is a bit ambiguous to me. Please edit your question and tell us exactly what you mean by `"... for the program to do nothing ..."`. In the edit, consider telling us **exactly** what the program is currently doing that you don't want it to do. The  better we can understand your problem, the better we can help. Also, consider creating and posting a [minimal example program or MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @dan_san_1: see edit to answer. Note that the details of the `enableExecution(...)` method will all depend on the details of your code and your problem.

Comment: I don't want it to pause during the blink, I want the program to **just blink** during those 2 seconds. Just wait 2 seconds

Comment: @dan_san_1: **again**, what do you mean by `"...then continue with the execution."`. The execution of **what**? Please help make your question answerable by providing these details. If we can understand your problem, we can help you.

Comment: OK, I'm about to give up. I hope someone else understands your request better. Regardless, I do wish you best of luck in solving this.

Comment: sorry for all the mess. Is there a way for the program to start blinking and then wait 2 seconds and then stops blinking? because what it happens is that in the program a JDialog pop up after the blinking start. I want that JDialog pop up 2 seconds after the blinking started

Comment: @dan_san_1: again, we're at an impasse regarding the `"wait 2 seconds"` bit. Do you want to disable the button and prevent the user from pressing it? Do you want to prevent the user from doing any interaction with the GUI? A glasspane can help with this. Again, please describe **in detail** and as an edit to your question, the full behaviors you're trying to achieve and what you're currently achieving. Again, create and post an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @dan_san_1: `"I want that JDialog pop up 2 seconds after the blinking started"` -- then show the JDialog from the `if (count >= maxCount) {` block. i.e., call it from the `enableExecution` method if `true` is passed in.

Comment: the JDialog is what happens after the blinking() method is called. It is on main(), I can't put it inside blinking(). What happens in main() after the blinking(), I want it to wait 2 seconds and only then pop up the JDialog.

Comment: @dan_san_1: There is no general restriction in Java that restricts the location of the code that displays JDialog. If your program is wired so that this can't be called from blinking, then change your program so that you can. If you need more help with this, again, edit your question, show us your [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and let's see how we can help you.

Comment: I have updated the question. Please read it and say if you understand it now. I has a reproduceble example

Comment: @dan_san_1: Thank you very much for the updated information and the code, 1+ to your question for this effort. Please see the edit to my answer. I believe that key to a solution is passing the necessary information to exactly where it is needed and then using it.

Comment: @dan_san_1: but note also that this, `"NOTE : I cannot move the JOptionPane out of main()."` is never an absolute requirement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72945/discussion-between-dan-san-1-and-hovercraft-full-of-eels).

Comment: @dan_san_1: see latest edit to answer. Another option is to use PropertyChangeListeners.